# Upload image to php webservice and store it in MSSQL database

Tags: php, sql-server, web-services, image-uploading, sqlsrv

I am trying to upload image to php web service and store it in MS SQL database. My post data is in json format which has  base64 encoded image data.

**Base 64 encode and insert sample**

```
$base=base64_encode(file_get_contents("C:\sample\images.jpg"));
$CommandText = "INSERT INTO [M_IMAGES] ([IMAGE_DATA]) VALUES(?) " ;
                 $ImageStream = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($this->imageData));
            $RowsAffected = (int)$objDBManager->Exe*emphasized text*cuteNonQuery($CommandText,array(array($ImageStream, 
                         SQLSRV_PARAM_IN,
                         SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STREAM(SQLSRV_ENC_BINARY),
                         SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARBINARY('max'))));
```

Here **$this->imageData** contanins base64 encoded image data and **IMAGE_DATA** datatype is image. I am able to upload and retrieve image successfully in normal upload

**Normal upload**

```
$ImagePath = $_FILES[$ImageCtrlName]['tmp_name'];
    $ImageStream = fopen($ImagePath, "r");
    $RowsAffected = (int)$objDBManager->ExecuteNonQuery($CommandText,
                        array(array(&$ImageStream,
                                 SQLSRV_PARAM_IN,
                                 SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STREAM(SQLSRV_ENC_BINARY),
                                 SQLSRV_SQLTYPE_VARBINARY('max'))));
    fclose($ImageStream);
```

I am getting error *sqlsrv_query(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource* 
Can anyone point out what is wrong here. Or is there a better way to do it. Help me as I am new to PHP.

Comment: I would not recommend storing images on databases as the base64 can get very very big.

Comment: @LFlare I will take your suggestion. But the existing production code stores image this way and I don't want to alter it.

Comment: It is perhaps in your best interest to migrate all the base64 images, convert them back to their original form and store them as files, not a column in a table. When it gets to the big 2-5MBs images, you will truly realise that storing images on a database is not recommended, in performance or in logic. **HOWEVER**, if you still plan to do that, I hope it's stored in a `text/longtext` type column

Comment: @LFlare Max image size is 1 MB and it is stored as image

Comment: I'm not too sure, `I am trying to upload image to php web service and store it in MS SQL database.` tells me that you are storing an image into a database? **EDIT: I realised your problem, please look at my answer.**

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to save in the DB only the url of the image and save the image in your server.
When you want to print it you only have to search the url in the DB.
Trying to save the image in a DB is a wrong solution.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand from your question, your problem stems from trying to store the image on to MSSQL as it's binary form, which is **not allowed**. What I can do, is advice you to store the image in it's **base64** form, which is a string of alphanumeric characters. There is no need to try and store the image as an image as the **base64** encoded image, is usually serve-able directly to the client.

**TL;DR Just store the image as base64.**

Comment: Image is base64_encoded so decoding while writing to database

Comment: @Gops **DO NOT** decode it and write to the database, the database won't accept binary. **TRY** writing it to the database in **base64**_encoded. If it isn't clear to you, you **cannot** write image files directly into the database

Comment: imagecreatefromstring() will throw error if we are not decoding image